# auto checking and submitting to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

i have one signup form where i have three field

username,password and email address

these three field will be stored in table A.when the user enters email address immediately i want to check table B (not table A which i checks while submitting) for the availability of that email address. if that email address is available in the table B then i want to take the id of corresponding email address from table B and insert that id in a hidden field below email which will be submitted with all fields when users click on submit  .please tell how to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your going to need is some simple AJAX magic, if you dont ahve it in your code yet, do yourself a favour and grab jQuery http://www.jquery.com and do something like this

```
<script>
    $("#email").change(function(e) {
        $.post("checkemail.php", { email: $(this).val() }, function(data) {
            if(data.available == "false") {
                $("#hidden_field_id").val(data.id);
            }
        }, "json");
    });
</script>
```

This will hit up your checkemail.php script with a POST (ensuring correct refreshed return data each time, unlike GET) the moment that someone has clicked or tabbed away from the field and javascript sees that the content has changed (so it only triggers once each time the content is different during the forms lifespan)

in you checkemail.php

```
$return = array("available"=>"true", "id"=>"");
$sql = mysql_query("select id from tableB where email='".trim($_POST['email'])."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
   $return['available'] = "false";
   $r = mysql_fetch_object($sql);
   $return['id'] = $r->id;
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

this is a very basic function that pings your database, if the email is found it will grab the id associated with that email (whatever that field happens to be in your database) and put it into our return array.
Once all is said and done, its going to echo out a JSON encoded array for use with Javascript (thats why in your script, there is a ,"json" paramater so the data is parsed and ready to use upon completion of the ajax call). If it finds that the email is unavailable, it will take the stored id number in the json object, and place it as the value of the designated hidden field in your form that your using to stash the returned id.

Hope that helps!